# Why use 95% confidence interval?

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

May I ask why $95\%$ confidence is so commonly used? Does it have anything to do with $\frac{d}{d\alpha}e_n(\alpha)$, where $e_n(\alpha) = Z_{\alpha/2}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}$? (My professor asks me to evaluate this derivative at $\alpha = 0.05$, given $S_n = 4.7, n = 100$.)

Comment: It's arbitrary.

Comment: I am 95% sure that the number is arbitrary :-). Maybe a vigesimal hangover?

Comment: There is a debate currently going on in various communities as to whether a lower $P$-value should become the tacit standard.

Comment: [A related CV question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652)

Comment: [**Obligatory comic**](https://xkcd.com/882) to show why it is stupid to just rely on 95% confidence in a world with publishing pressure!

Comment: To be able to publish more. It used to be more strict...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [Wikipedia article *1.96*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96) :

> The use of this number in applied statistics can be traced to the
>   influence of Ronald Fisher's classic textbook, Statistical Methods for
>   Research Workers, first published in 1925:
>
> "The value for which P = .05, or 1 in 20, is 1.96 or nearly 2 ; it is 
>   convenient to take this point as a limit in judging whether   a 
>   deviation is to be considered significant or not."

Comment: It is worth noting that Fisher was working at the Rothamsted Experimental Station on crop research, so this $2$ standard deviation rule-of-thumb is likely to be something he had found practically useful

Answer (score 8):

$95\%$ is just the conventionally accepted boundary for "reasonably certain" in general cases. It has nothing to do with any specific formulas, and is rather an arbitrary choice that statisticians have agreed is a good compromise between getting results at all and getting results we can trust.

Comment: Though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis indicates there might be good reason to shift to higher confidence intervals.  Also: https://xkcd.com/882/

Comment: @DanielSchleper There is an XKCD for anything.

Comment: @DanielSchepler "5% of all the research is actually wrong" is a mind-boglingly **huge** number, given how many papers are published every day. Imagine an enterprise that has the 1-to-20 ratio of rejects in its production.

Comment: @Joker_vD: I think its even worse than that -- I imagine wrong results are much more likely to be publishable than right ones.

Comment: @Joker_vD : Veritasium did a great YouTube video on this entitled "Why most research is wrong." Worth watching

Comment: Changing the percentage accepted as significant would do little or nothing to resolve the "replication crisis". It is routed in the methods and culture of science and, in particular, scientific publishing and funding.

Comment: @JackAidley There isn't enough incentive in attempting to replicate other studies compared to making new science.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is arbitrary because given a normal distribution

```
68.27% of all values lie within 1 standard deviation
95.45% of all values lie within 2 standard deviations and
99.73% of all values lie within 3 standard deviations
```

Comment: But the multiples of standard deviation are themselves arbitrary.

Comment: @JeremyC: Indeed. Why not consider the percent of values within $\frac{2154}{1099}$ many standard deviations?